# Angular complains cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular template like below.

```
<section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <form [formGroup]="testForm">
          <div class="columns is-multiline">
            <div class="column is-2">
              <div class="box">
                <h1 class="subtitle">Test Array</h1>
                <div formArrayName="salestest" *ngFor="let sale of salestest.controls; let i=index">
                  <div [formGroupName]="i">
                    <div class="field">
                      <label class="label">Test Sale1</label>
                      <div class="control">
                        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Sales" formControlName="sales">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
```

I have an Component like this

```
export class SalesTestComponent implements OnInit {
  testForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testForm = this.fb.group({
      salestest: this.fb.array([this.buildSalesTest()])
    });
    console.log("ngOnint was called");
  }

  buildSalesTest(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      sales: ""
    });
  }

   get salestest(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.testForm.get("salestest");
  }
}
```

When i build and run this i get an error saying

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

And line 3 in the template is

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
```

I am not sure why angular is complaining of cannot read property of undefined.

Here is the entire error message

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (CreateSalesTestComponent.html:23)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:23838)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23213)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23449)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23391)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23214)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23449)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23412)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23209)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23449)
```

And line 23 is

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.testForm = this.fb.group({
      salestest: this.fb.array([this.buildSalesTest()])
    }); <!-- **Line 23** -->
    console.log("ngOnint was called");
  }
```

Comment: error is on line no 3?

Comment: Hi Yes it says error on line no 3 which is <form [formGroup]="testForm"> in the template and the error message is Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Can you post the whole error message? I've tried your code and it works fine

Comment: Can you post all `CreateSalesTestComponent.html` file?

Comment: The error comes from your **html** file not *ts*. You can even click on that error in console and it will bring you to the place where it happened

Comment: Hi Yurzui thank you so much for taking a look at it But that is my complete html file :)

Comment: Ohh Mr Yurzui you are correct i had some special character in my html file the issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Following line is wrong.

```
<div [formGroupName]="i">
```

Change it to

```
<div [formGroup]="sale">
```

You are assigning index to the formGroupName. That is why your form attribute can't find group and its controls in it.
Here is a [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-case-form-fix?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Let me know if there is a problem, I'll be more than happy to help.